# Facebook social plugin comments after URL change

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, comments, alias

Just a simple question, I had facebook comments integrated in my page here:

http://www.bbcnepalidrama.com/main/node/3

Now I have changed the URL alias like this:

http://www.bbcnepalidrama.com/main/about

I have also set a 301 redirect in the old URL which redirects to the new one.
The Question is how do I get the old comments in this URL? They are missing now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 1):

I think, that these comments will be forever associated with that URL and since you've changed it, as far as FB is concerned you are pointing to a different URL.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the old URL as “canonical” with an `og:url` meta tag.
see the [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs) about this.

Answer (score 0):

This sucks in Facebook comments. I've launched a site with Facebook comments integrated, without setting the URL, and now when I do, the comments doesn't show up.

Your case seems to be easy, since it seems you're using Drupal. You can install the token and token_filter modules, so you can add the facebook comments code to a block and use the appropriate token that will return the node id from the current page.