# Facebook Comments and Likes For Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

So, I have an interesting question here.  Right now, I have a facebook comments app on my blog, howmanyfrogs.com - I updated my permalink structure because another plugin broke it, and now all my comments, although they are showing under my application on facebook at this link here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=254902427882384 they aren't displaying on the website because facebook can't find the page they are supposed to go on.  I was wondering if there was a way in the facebook app to repoint them to the correct link?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133406/facebook-social-plugin-comments-after-url-change

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the data-href myself and it hasn't made a difference.  I would think the best solution would be to associate it with the shortlink (since that never changes) and display it even with the longer friendly urls.

```
<div class="fb-comments" href="<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>"></div>
```

It works, but I lose all my comments made before when I used permalink.  (quite annoying, believe me.)

However, since the link now goes to the post not the pretty link of the post it stays with the post even when the url changes (i.e. due to moving the post between categories)

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) and Likes are tied to a URL - which is basically Open Graph Object identifier. So when you changed your URLs (permalinks), the Comments and Like plugins think they are on a new page (the new URL) with no comments.

You'll need to figure out a way to pass the old permalink into your Comments Plugin call, I think. That should bring up the lost comments.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="YOUR OLD POST URL"></div>
```

I'm not sure the best way to do that though... you might have to write custom WordPress function (in `functions.php`) that generates the old URLs based on the new URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you told us your old permalink structure and your new one. I did some Googling and it looks like [this guy had some success](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-how-to-change-permalinks-without-losing-facebook-commentslikes?replies=1). Maybe look at how he solved this issue.