# Facebook comment box migrating to another domain

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

How can I change my site domain and keeping existing comments?

I'm using html5 data attributes, like this: data-href="http://domain/somespecificid" and I want to change to data-href="http://new_domain/somespecificid".

If I keeping the old href, i got an error message: Warning: *url* is unreachable.

Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Very Short: You can`t
[Facebook social plugin comments after URL change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133406/facebook-social-plugin-comments-after-url-change)
Facebook comments are synchronized to a URL you give. 
But you can change it dynamically. Look at this post 
[How to dynamically change facebook comments plugin url based on javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122633/how-to-dynamically-change-facebook-comments-plugin-url-based-on-javascript-varia)